# Make Nginx fail when SSL certificate not present, instead of hopping to only available certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've got a bunch of websites on a server, all hosted through nginx. One site has a certificate, the others do not. Here's an example of two sites, using (fairly accurate) representations of real configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ssl.example.com;
    return 301 https://ssl.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ssl.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nossl.example.com;
}
```

SSL works on `ssl.example.com` great. If I visit `http://nossl.example.com`, that works great, but if I try to visit `https://nossl.example.com` (note the SSL), I get ugly warnings about the certificate being for `ssl.example.com`.

By the sounds of it, because `ssl.example.com` is the only site listening on port 443, all requests are being sent to it, regardless of domain name.

Is there anything I can do to make sure a Nginx server directive only responds to domains it's responsible for?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different IP address for the hosts which should never answer on SSL, and ensure that nginx only listens on port 443 for the appropriate IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to really segregate ssl sites, sans multi-host/wildcard ssl cert, is to add secondary public ip's to your box (must request via provider).

then, you put each site/subdomain on its own ip via dns. that way, some domainname:443 will be open, and some will spin until timeout (by using DROP via iptables)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the domain (via the `Host` header) is part of the encrypted payload. Thus, nginx doesn't know what domain it's for until after it has presented the certificate. This is a technical limitation of SSL, not nginx.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication may help, but IE users on XP (still a decent percentage of Internet users) can't use it.

Comment: _but IE users on XP (still a decent percentage of Internet users) can't use it._ What? http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201308-201310-bar